# Linux Device Drivers: Sleeping whiile Holding Lock Revisited

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've always been taught that sleeping while holding a spinlock in kernel code is a no-no.  The reason for this is the following scenario:

1. Thread A acquires the lock, does some work, and calls a kernel function that goes to sleep, releasing the CPU.
2. Thread B now runs, which attempts to acquire the lock, but can't since its held by Thread A.
3. This is a deadlock.  Thread A can't get woken up since Thread B is constantly spinning and Thread B can't make any progress since it can't get the lock.

I am maintaining a driver which uses lots of locks and inside some of the locked sections are obvious things like memory allocations, `copy_to_user()`, etc.

However, I am not entirely convinced that I have a bug on my hands.  Using the above scenario, Thread A is user context (namely inside the implementation of `read()`) while Thread B is the interrupt context (inside the ISR).  The lock is locked via `spin_lock_irqsave()`.  As a result, Thread B cannot run while Thread A holds the lock, making the deadlock not possible.

I have also considered the following:

1. Thread A = interrupt context.  Here Thread A cannot sleep (and doesn't) so we never get into the deadlock condition.
2. Thread A and B are both user context (i.e., concurrent calls to `read()` ).  This cannot happen due to other mechanisms in place.

Is there anything that I am missing?  In what I described above, is there any real danger related to sleeping while holding the lock?

Comment: *...a driver which uses lots of locks...* — design smells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not add up.

> Using the above scenario, Thread A is user context (namely inside the
>   implementation of read()) while Thread B is the interrupt context
>   (inside the ISR). The lock is locked via spin_lock_irqsave(). As a
>   result, Thread B cannot run while Thread A holds the lock, making the
>   deadlock not possible.

If you hold the spinlock across copy_to_user & friends, the kernel with debug will warn you that you are doing it wrong. Should the need to put the thread to sleep occur, it will go to sleep. Then you are back to square one.

Comment: I understand that the kernel will warn me, but why is it warning me?  What's the specific scenario that can break things?  How does my question not add up?  If the user context acquires the lock first, there's no way for the ISR to attempt to obtain the lock since interrupts have been disabled.

Comment: I explicitly said that you holding the spinlock around copy_to_user and similar functions has no effect on their ability to put you to sleep. Interrupts are not going to remain disabled across your sleep - this would already break the kernel. And from there the other lock consumer runs into trouble. What does not add up is your assertion that a sleepable function is not going to put you to sleep because you have interrupts disabled.

Comment: Just read your edits, I never said that I wouldn't sleep, sorry for the confusion.  To make sure I understand... If copy_to_user() puts me to sleep, interrupts are re-enabled (undoing my spin_lock_irqsave()), the ISR can now run, and as a result very bad things can happen... is that correct?

Comment: correct. basically copy_to_user does not expect interrupts to be disabled to begin with and disabling/enabling them does not stack - disabling while disabled is a noop. then enabling gets them enabled, no matter how many times you disabled. so when it plays with them later (if necessary) they end up getting enabled

Answer (score 3):

> I've always been taught that sleeping while holding a spinlock in kernel code is a no-no.

You confuse **spinlocks** and **disabled interrupts** (atomic context, IRQ).

1. Just **sleeping** while having a **spinlock** (acquired with `spin_lock`) harms *perfomance*, because the other thread, wanting to lock the spinlock, wastes a time with busy wait. But otherwise the system is OK.
2. But **sleeping** with **disabled interrupts** means the CPU core is *dead*: it executes nothing and doesn't react on interrupts from the other cores and outer world.

   This is what would happen, if your call `spin_lock_irqsave` followed by `copy_from_user`: the first operations disables interrupts, and the second may sleep.

---

Usually **disabled interrupts** accompanies **spinlocks** (by means of `spin_lock_irqsave` or similar). Otherwise, if IRQ thread will attempt to acquire the same spinlock, *deadlock* will be observed: owner thread cannot proceed because it is preempted, and IRQ thread cannot proceed because it waits on spinlock.

Disabling interrupts is not needed for taking some spinlock, if no IRQ thread(or a thread with interrupts disabled for other reason) locks given spinlock. When disabling interrupts is not needed, `spin_lock` can be used instead of `spin_lock_irqsave`. But it is **very recommended** to replace non-IRQ spinlocks with *mutexes*.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding your answer... if you sleep inside of code that has acquired a lock with spin_lock_irqsave(), there is no way for the thread to wake up, since it requires an interrupt to do so and those have been turned off?  Is that correct?

Comment: Also, I'm not following along with #1.  Isn't it a deadlock to sleep with a "regular" spinlock because of the scenario outlined in my question?  Or is this more of an issue with the scheduler, since the sleeping process *can* wake up once it gets another time slice?

Comment: there is no guarantee the kernel will recover from a sleeping spinlock owner and in some cases it can't (e.g. when preemption is disabled or voluntary). Basically your answer requires so many asterisks after it I don't think it is of much use on this forum.

Comment: @It'sPete: `Thread A can't get woken up since Thread B is constantly spinning` - just spinning doesn't prevent thread B to be preempted. You may think about spinning as intensive work - such work doesn't break the kernel. So your conclusion about deadlock isn't correct. As for sleeping inside `spin_lock_irqsave`, yes - there is no way for the thread to wake up, since interrupts are disabled.

Comment: @employeeofthemonth: `there is no guarantee the kernel will recover from a sleeping spinlock owner` - What do you mean by "recovering from owner"? As for disabled preemption, sleeping during it is **bad by itself**. But again, spinlocks **doesn't imply** disabled preemption. `spin_lock` doesn't disable preemption, `spin_lock_irqsave` disables preemption and interrupts, and this case is explicitely described in my question.

Comment: Linux can be compiled to treat preemption in different ways, in particular I mentioned when there is no preemption whatsoever OR preemption checks only performed in specific places. In fact this is what happens in most common configurations (see CONFIG_PREEMPT). In this scenario it is completely legitimate the blocked spinlock owner will never get on the cpu, thus the kernel will not recover. Most important point is that this is a discussion how much potential breakage is induced by doing something wrong to begin with (sleeping with a spinlock). I don't think it useful at this level.

Comment: Hmm, OK. So busy waiting break a rule, that any kernel code should eventually hit a "safe point", where it is allowed for the process to be preempted.